# SELECT WHERE subselect SUM applies to condition

Tags: mysql

Here's my sample DB:

```
orderID |name |invoiceTotal |packGroup
--------------------------------------
123     |john |5.49         |abc
456     |bill |10.00        |def  
789     |bill |10.00        |def
```

Some customers have one order, some place more than one but to the same delivery address. The app user will decide if Bill's two orders should be shipped together in one package. If so, the field "packGroup" is set to the same unique string.

Now I want to list orders giving the user the option to select i.e. a price range (and other properties like delivery country, referrer etc.).

So, I can easily do the following to display orders in a price range.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE ... 
   AND amountTotal/exchangeRatio > 15 
   AND amountTotal/exchangeRatio < 50 
 GROUP 
    BY packGroup
```

Now I want to display just ONE cumulated order for Bill listing a total invoice amount of 20.

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders 
 WHERE ... 
   AND (SELECT SUM(amountTotal)/exchangeRatio 
          FROM orders o 
         WHERE packGroup=o.packGroup) > 15 
   AND (SELECT SUM(amountTotal)/exchangeRatio 
          FROM orders o 
         WHERE packGroup=o.packGroup) < 50 
 GROUP 
    BY packGroup
```

But I get 0 results.
My problem is not to display "20" but to have Bill's orders fall into the condition where the price range between 15 and 50 applies.

To clarify: "exchangeRatio" is another field in the table being different from 1 when the order was placed in another foreign currency.

**Update:** 
[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5a931/3)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry for the edit, looks much more comprehensible now. :)

Comment: Could you create an http://sqlfiddle.com/ entry for the issue?

Comment: And thanks for the link. I do think my example is complete though, definetely minimal.

Comment: `select sum(amountTotal)/exchangeRatio where amountTotal/exchangeRatio>15 and amountTotal/exchangeRatio<50 group by name`?

Comment: @Brian thanks, never tried this one before. Somehow it seems not to accept my (very simple INSERT statements). I will add them to the question.

Comment: You cannot use backtics (`\``) for values .. Use `'`

Comment: @harpax thanks for the tip. That was the problem.
Here's the fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5a931/3) Strangely, sqlfiddle also gives me results that don't fall into the price range. When I do the same in MySQL Workbench, I have 0 results.

Comment: @Brick unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. I have to `select *` and want Bill's orders in the result set because he spent 20 bucks in two orders. So his should show up when selected price range includes 20. And also I cannot `GROUP BY name` since there may be other customers by that name. :)

Comment: @Engle In that case, it seems that your requirements are incompatible and/or your db is not structured in a way that supports them. Either that or I'm with the earlier comment about the suitability of your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's this one:

```
SELECT orders.*, SUM(amountTotal)/exchangeRatio AS sum_total
FROM orders
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY orders.packGroup
HAVING sum_total>15 AND sum_total<50
```

or if you want all rows that match the clause:

```
SELECT orders.*
FROM orders
WHERE 1=1
AND packGroup = (SELECT o.packGroup 
FROM orders AS o
GROUP BY o.packGroup
HAVING (SUM(o.amountTotal/o.exchangeRatio)) BETWEEN 15 AND 50)
```

Comment: first tries are very promising, let me implement it, then I'll know if this is the answer. :)

Comment: very awesome! Thank you. Works like a charm